# How to upload a file through a websocket?

Tags: go, websocket

I have a WebSocket connection between a client and a server and I cannot find any clear example explaining how to upload a file on the server through this WebSocket.

I previously made a REST API that performs this task using a multipart form, allowing me to send some extra info, like the file name, in headers. I have no idea how to do something similar with the WebSocket. I suppose one solution would be to send a JSON with the filename and the file converted in base64, but would it be OK even for large files?

Comment: refering to https://github.com/gorilla/websocket  The writer you get after calling NextWriter already implements the logic requred to split the data in frames suitable for that connection, and upon calling Close it flushes its data. You can read here the logic of the Write implementation https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/v1.4.2/conn.go#L650 and here you can convince yourself that closing the conn, flushes the underlying data https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b65e62901fc1c0d968042419e74789f6af455eb9/conn.go#L720

Comment: note that you can send binary data, if you set the message type appropriately. NextWriter take a messageType argument https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.NextWriter which you can find here https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/v1.4.2/conn.go#L62

Comment: because websocket implementation is 1to1 packet oriented connection, you could send a first packet to announce the file to be transfered in text/json/whatever, then get another writer of type binary to copy the file to as raw binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In fact, the custom framework used in my company can only send/receive string (JSON) messages through the websocket. So I think I have no choice but using base64 encoding. I will split large files in chunks on the client, encode them in base64 and do the decoding and merge on the server.

Comment: its a JS client or a go client ? I did not understand sorry

Comment: If you are using this websocket connection for other purposes as well, it may make sense to use websocket, only to obtain the token for the upload, and perform the upload itself on a separate connection.

Comment: The client is made with Qt, but there might be other types of clients in the future. The websocket is used for other things than just file upload, action are made before and after the files uploads, the server perform a treatment on files and stream progress of this treatment back to the client. If the base64 solution doesn't work, I'll stick to the existing API multipart form solution.